# Pulling data from one table even when the related table has not valid data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have three tables, two of them have a 1 to many relationship (Tables A & B) and the third is a LookUp table (table LU). I want to pull all records where Status (on both tables) <> 'D'.

In my situation table A does not have a Status = 'D', however, all of table B's related records have a status = 'D'. So what I need to do is pull the one record from table A and none from table B (since it does not have any valid related records).

Here is my query which does not return anything in the scenario I describe:

```
SELECT A.Field1, 
        A.Field2, 
        A.KeyField1, 
        LU.LookUpField, 
        B.Field1, 
        B.Field2, 
FROM TableA A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB B ON A.KeyField1 = B.KeyField1 
AND A.KeyField2 = B.KeyField2 
JOIN LookUpTable LU ON LU.FieldID = B.FieldID 
WHERE A.KeyField = '11111' 
AND ISNULL(A.Status, SPACE(0)) <> 'D' 
AND ISNULL(B.Status, SPACE(0)) <> 'D' 
ORDER BY A.KeyField, LU.SortOrder
```

I tried a `UNION` where I'd just bring back blank fields when Table B didn't have valid data. But when records from both tables have valid data I brought back that extra row with blank fields which I don't want in my first scenario.

Comment: `FULL OUTER JOIN`?

Comment: Thanks but Full OUTER JOIN didn't work.

Comment: Surely someone can solve this? The query brings back all rows if I remove the AND ISNULL(B.Status, SPACE(0)) <> 'D' but that is not what I want so this line is the obvious issue. I tried replacing that line with AND EXISTS (Select DISTINCT KeyField1  FROM TableB WHERE KeyField1  = '11111' AND ISNULL(Status, SPACE(0)) <> 'D') but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaron Bertrand at StackExchange solved this for me. All I had to do was change:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB B ON A.KeyField1 = B.KeyField1 
AND A.KeyField2 = B.KeyField2 
JOIN LookUpTable LU ON LU.FieldID = B.FieldID 
WHERE A.KeyField = '11111' 
AND ISNULL(A.Status, SPACE(0)) <> 'D' 
AND ISNULL(B.Status, SPACE(0)) <> 'D'
```

to

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB B ON A.KeyField1 = B.KeyField1 
AND A.KeyField2 = B.KeyField2 
AND ISNULL(B.Status, SPACE(0)) <> 'D' 
JOIN LookUpTable LU ON LU.FieldID = B.FieldID 
WHERE A.KeyField = '11111' 
AND ISNULL(A.Status, SPACE(0)) <> 'D'
```